# node.js send disconnect event after closing server (ctrl-C)?

Tags: java, node.js

I have a java client that is connected to a node.js server. On the java client I have this code for disconnection:

```
public void onDisconnect() {
    // Socket connection closed
    System.out.println("disconnect");
}
```

This code is not triggered when I close the server (ctrl-C from my linux command line). 
Is there a way to notify the client that the server was closed?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it eventually.
I added a Timer on the java client side that periodically checks if the socket is still alive:

```
private Timer checkNodejsConnectionTimer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("check nodejs");
                        if ((socket_already_connected)&&(!socket.isConnected())) {
                            socket_already_connected = false;
                            socket.disconnect();
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Server disconnected. Please try again later.");
                            checkNodejsConnectionTimer.stop();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I hope this will help someone else with the same problem.